# cannot get user variable $env:*** by gitlab-ci.yml and shell executor

Tags: powershell, gitlab, cicd, gitlab-ci.yml

**Gitlab-CI**

here is an exmaple to describe my probelm.
config.toml:

```
[[runners]]
    name = ...
    url = ...
    ...
    executor = shell
    shell = "powershell"
    ....
```

.gitlab-ci.yml :

```
test-job:
   tags:
      - test-runner
   script:
      - echo $env:windir
      - echo $env:OneDrive
```

output:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 15.2.1
...
...
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
...
...
...
$ echo $env:windir
C:\Windows
$ echo $env:OneDrive
Job succeeded
```

**Issue**

As you can see, there is no output of "echo $env:OneDrive" because $env:OneDrive is an user variable. But i can get the output of "echo $env:windir" because $env:windir is a system variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there is no output of "echo $env:OneDrive" because $env:OneDrive is an user variable. But i can get the output of "echo $env:windir" because $env:windir is a system variable.

Seems like you kind of answered your own question here. That is the expected (system-defined) behavior for GitLab powershell runners -- All powershell commands are executed with the [`-NoProfile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1#-noprofile) option, meaning profiles are not used and user environment variables will not be loaded.

There is a [feature request](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/4315) to be able to configure this behavior, but at the time of writing, this capability is not available. Therefore, you must set any such environment variables another way (say, as system variables, in the runner settings, instance settings, or group/project CICD settings).